# Can we Reset DB values to old one??

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In Android Sqlite DB is there is any chance of Resetting value to the old one(That is values before change).
Am having a button Reset. If the User clicks that btn it should reset back the old values.

Comment: Where is the "old value" maintained?  Are you keeping a history of data somewhere?  What specifically are you trying to update?

Comment: no am not storing any history of data. Am having values in db. If i change that, can i get back the values that is before changed

Comment: Not if you aren't retaining those values anywhere.  You can roll back a transaction so that a change doesn't take effect.  But once you've modified data, that data has been modified.  If you want to modify it again to another value (previous or otherwise), then you need to have that other value so you can modify it the same way.

Comment: Ok .. Then i will maintain a history of data somewhere.. Thanks a lot @David

Comment: Hm ok. Nice idea .. Thanks a lot @FrankN.Stein

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, so you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide some kind of a "factory reset", you could simply put a pre-filled "default" database in the `assets` folder.
Then overwrite the existing database with that one by pressing your "reset" Button.